# html form with php issue

Tags: php, html, forms

I have made a html form where the user can enter his name/email/phone etc. and also select quantity of the listed products.

Here is the product code and I'm wondering how do I do to include in the email message I get from the form to include how many of what product the user wants.

This is the form code:

```
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 bottom-padding">
    <?php
        process_si_contact_form();

        if (isset($_SESSION['ctform']['error']) &&  $_SESSION['ctform']['error'] == true):
    ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Oops!</strong> Something went wrong.
        </div>
    <?php
        elseif (isset($_SESSION['ctform']['success']) && $_SESSION['ctform']['success'] == true):
    ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <strong>Message sent!</strong> We'll get in touch asap.
        </div>
    <?php
        endif;
    ?>
    <form class="form-box register-form contact-form" method="POST" id="contact_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="do" value="contact" />
        <h3 class="title">Form</h3>
        <label>Name: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo @$_SESSION['ctform']['f_name_error'] ?>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ct_f_name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(@$_SESSION['ctform']['ct_f_name']) ?>">
        <label>E-mail: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo @$_SESSION['ctform']['f_email_error'] ?>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="ct_f_email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(@$_SESSION['ctform']['ct_f_email']) ?>">
        <label>Phone: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo @$_SESSION['ctform']['f_tel_error'] ?>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ct_f_tel" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(@$_SESSION['ctform']['ct_f_tel']) ?>">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" class="collapsed">
                            Hardware
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="list-group checked-list-box">
                            <?php
                                $my_products = array(   
                                    '1' => 'Product 1',
                                    '2' => 'Product 2',
                                    '3' => 'Product 3'
                                );

                                foreach ($my_products as $key => $value) {
                                    echo "<div class=\"col-xs-6\" style=\"margin: 10px 0 5px 0;\">";
                                        echo "<li class=\"list-group-item\" data-style=\"button\">";
                                            echo $value;
                                            echo "<select class=\"form-control\" name=\"quantity[$key]>\"";
                                                for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
                                            echo "</select>";
                                        echo "</li>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" class="collapsed">
                            Software
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Empty.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <label>Message: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo @$_SESSION['ctform']['message_error'] ?>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="ct_message"><?php echo htmlspecialchars(@$_SESSION['ctform']['ct_message']) ?></textarea>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="buttons-box clearfix">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Send">
            <span class="required"><b>*</b> Required fields</span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Anything else I need to post? I don't know if this is the best way coded but it does the work. Now it won't let me save this question because it's much code included in this post so I'm writing to be able to save it lol.

EDIT: ADDING PHP FORM CODE.

```
 <?php
        function process_si_contact_form() {
            $_SESSION['ctform'] = array();
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && @$_POST['do'] == 'contact') {

            foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
                if (!is_array($key)) {
                    if ($key != 'ct_message') $value = strip_tags($value);
                    $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($value)));
                }
            }
            $f_name = @$_POST['ct_f_name'];
            $f_tel = @$_POST['ct_f_tel'];
            $f_email = @$_POST['ct_f_email'];
            $message = @$_POST['ct_message'];
            $f_name = substr($f_name, 0, 64);
            $errors = array();
            if (isset($GLOBALS['DEBUG_MODE']) && $GLOBALS['DEBUG_MODE'] == false) {
                if (strlen($f_name) < 3) {
                    $errors['f_name_error'] = 'Your name please.';
                }
                if (strlen($f_tel) < 10) {
                    $errors['f_tel_error'] = 'Your phone please.';
                } else if (!preg_match('/^([-+0-9()]+)$/', $f_tel)) {
                    $errors['f_tel_error'] = 'Thats not a phone number!';
                }
                if (strlen($f_email) == 0) {
                    $errors['f_email_error'] = 'Your e-mail please.';
                } else if (!preg_match('/^(?:[\w\d]+\.?)+@(?:(?:[\w\d]\-?)+\.)+\w{2,4}$/i', $f_email)) {
                    $errors['f_email_error'] = 'Thats not an e-mail!';
                }
                if (strlen($message) < 10) {
                    $errors['message_error'] = 'Your message must contain atleast 10 characters.';
                }
            }
            if (sizeof($errors) == 0) {
                $time = date('r');
                $message = "<strong>Name:</strong><br /><em>$f_name</em><br />"
                    . "<br />"
                    . "<strong>E-mail:</strong><br /><em>$f_email</em><br />"
                    . "<br />"
                    . "<strong>Phone:</strong><br /><em>$f_tel</em>"
                    . "<br /><br /><br />"
                    . "<strong>Message:</strong><br />"
                    . "<pre>$message</pre>"
                    . "<br /><br />"
                    . "<strong>IP:</strong><br /><em>{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}</em><br />"
                    . "<br />"
                    . "<strong>Time:</strong><br /><em>$time</em><br />"
                    . "<br />"
                    . "<strong>Browser:</strong><br /><em>{$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']}</em>";
                $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
                if (isset($GLOBALS['DEBUG_MODE']) && $GLOBALS['DEBUG_MODE'] == false) {

                    mail($GLOBALS['ct_recipient'], $GLOBALS['ct_msg_subject'], $message, "From: {$GLOBALS['ct_recipient_no_reply']}\r\nReply-To: {$f_email}\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=utf8\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0");
                }
                $_SESSION['ctform']['error'] = false;
                $_SESSION['ctform']['success'] = true;
            } else {
                $_SESSION['ctform']['ct_f_name'] = $f_name;
                $_SESSION['ctform']['ct_f_tel'] = $f_tel;
                $_SESSION['ctform']['ct_f_email'] = $f_email;
                $_SESSION['ctform']['ct_message'] = $message;
                foreach($errors as $key => $error) {
                    $_SESSION['ctform'][$key] = "<span class=\"error\" style=\"float: right; color: 00ff00;\">$error</span>";
                }
                $_SESSION['ctform']['error'] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    $_SESSION['ctform']['success'] = false;
    ?>

EDIT 2: ADDING NEW PHP MAIL CODE.

<?php
    function process_si_contact_form() {
        $_SESSION['ctform'] = array();
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && @$_POST['do'] == 'contact') {

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_array($key)) {
                if ($key != 'ct_message') $value = strip_tags($value);
                $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($value)));
            }
        }
        $f_name = @$_POST['ct_f_name'];
        $f_tel = @$_POST['ct_f_tel'];
        $f_email = @$_POST['ct_f_email'];
        $message = @$_POST['ct_message'];
        $f_name = substr($f_name, 0, 64);
        $products = array(
            @$_POST['quantity[1]'], 
            @$_POST['quantity[2]'],
            @$_POST['quantity[3]'],
            @$_POST['quantity[4]'],
            @$_POST['quantity[5]'],
            @$_POST['quantity[6]'],
            @$_POST['quantity[7]'],
            @$_POST['quantity[8]'],
            @$_POST['quantity[9]'],
            @$_POST['quantity[10]']);
        $errors = array();
        if (isset($GLOBALS['DEBUG_MODE']) && $GLOBALS['DEBUG_MODE'] == false) {
            if (strlen($f_name) < 3) {
                $errors['f_name_error'] = 'Fyll i ditt namn';
            }
            if (strlen($f_tel) < 10) {
                $errors['f_tel_error'] = 'Fyll i ditt tel.nr';
            } else if (!preg_match('/^([-+0-9()]+)$/', $f_tel)) {
                $errors['f_tel_error'] = 'Felaktigt tel.nr';
            }
            if (strlen($f_email) == 0) {
                $errors['f_email_error'] = 'Fyll i din e-postadress';
            } else if (!preg_match('/^(?:[\w\d]+\.?)+@(?:(?:[\w\d]\-?)+\.)+\w{2,4}$/i', $f_email)) {
                $errors['f_email_error'] = 'Felaktig e-postadress';
            }
            if (strlen($message) < 10) {
                $errors['message_error'] = 'Ditt meddelande måste bestå av minst 10 tecken';
            }
        }
        if (sizeof($errors) == 0) {
            $time = date('r');
            $message = "<strong>Namn:</strong><br /><em>$f_name</em><br />"
                . "<br />"
                . "<strong>E-postadress:</strong><br /><em>$f_email</em><br />"
                . "<br />"
                . "<strong>Telefon:</strong><br /><em>$f_tel</em>"
                . "<br /><br /><br />"
                . "<strong>Meddelande:</strong><br />"
                . "<pre>$message</pre>"
                . "<br />"
                . "<strong>IP:</strong><br /><em>{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}</em><br />"
                . "<br /><strong>".$products[1]." - Ingenico IPP350</strong>"
                . "<br /><strong>".$products[2]." - Ingenico ICT250</strong>"
                . "<br /><strong>".$products[3]." - Yomani</strong>"
                . "<br /><strong>".$products[4]." - Ingenico IWL250 GPRS</strong>"
                . "<br /><strong>".$products[5]." - PosBank&reg; AnyShop II</strong>"
                . "<br /><strong>".$products[6]." - Ingenico IWL250 Wifi</strong>"
                . "<br /><strong>".$products[7]." - Ingenico IWL250 BT</strong>"
                . "<br /><strong>".$products[8]." - PosBank&reg AnyShop e2</strong>"
                . "<br /><strong>".$products[9]." - Ingenico IWL285 3G</strong>"
                . "<br /><strong>".$products[10]." - Ingenico iCMP</strong>"
                . "<br /><br /><strong>Tid:</strong><br /><em>$time</em><br />"
                . "<br />"
                . "<strong>Webbläsare:</strong><br /><em>{$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']}</em>";
            $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
            if (isset($GLOBALS['DEBUG_MODE']) && $GLOBALS['DEBUG_MODE'] == false) {

                mail($GLOBALS['ct_recipient'], $GLOBALS['ct_msg_subject'], $message, "From: {$GLOBALS['ct_recipient_no_reply']}\r\nReply-To: {$f_email}\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=utf8\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0");
            }
            $_SESSION['ctform']['error'] = false;
            $_SESSION['ctform']['success'] = true;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['ctform']['ct_f_name'] = $f_name;
            $_SESSION['ctform']['ct_f_tel'] = $f_tel;
            $_SESSION['ctform']['ct_f_email'] = $f_email;
            $_SESSION['ctform']['ct_message'] = $message;
            foreach($errors as $key => $error) {
                $_SESSION['ctform'][$key] = "<span class=\"error\" style=\"float: right; color: 00ff00;\">$error</span>";
            }
            $_SESSION['ctform']['error'] = true;
        }
    }
}
$_SESSION['ctform']['success'] = false;
?>
```

Comment: We would need to see the form as well.

Comment: And the PHP script to go with it. (which sends the email)

Comment: `"how do I do to include in the email message"` - What email message?  There's no code here which sends an email...

Comment: I've added the form code now

Comment: still no mail-function anywhere...

Comment: Is the email message the textarea with the name `ct_message`? Also is the "items" the user wants the `select` tags in `<ul class="list-group checked-list-box">`?

Comment: I added the php code. The form sends all the fields, phone, name and message. I want it to send the products that are selected aswell. Yes, the select tags are how many of what product is wanted which i then want in the message.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` of these elements would be: `quantity[0]`, `quantity[1]`, and `quantity[2]` which contains the value gave for each product. Notice if you want a `quantity[0]` you need to include that in the `$my_products` array. The value for `Product 1` would be in `quantity[1]`. The information is from this code here:

```
$my_products = array(   
    '0' => 'Product 0', /* Added Product 0 */
    '1' => 'Product 1',
    '2' => 'Product 2'
);

foreach ($my_products as $key => $value) {
    ...
            // $key is 0,1,2 through the loop so the name would be 
            // quantity[0] quantity[1], and quantity[2]
            echo "<select class=\"form-control\" name=\"quantity[$key]>\"";
                for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
            echo "</select>";
    ...
}
```

So you would just get name in the same way you got your other POST data in your PHP form code:

```
$products = array(
    @$_POST['quantity[0]'], 
    @$_POST['quantity[1]'], 
    @$_POST['quantity[2]'] );
```

Now just include those values in your `$message`:

```
$message =
    /* Your normal message content here from the code */
    . "<strong>Product0:</strong><br /><em>".$products[0]."</em><br />"
    . "<br />"
    . "<strong>Product1:</strong><br /><em>".$products[1]".</em><br />"
    . "<br />"
    . "<strong>Product2:</strong><br /><em>".$products[2]."</em><br />"
    . "<br />";
```

Comment: Thank you mate! Is there anyway I could make it abit easier? Like, without having to do so many variables for each product etc.

and also how do I fix the for loop, I want the quantity to start at 0 not at 1.

Comment: @JamesJ. Yes, as I mentioned you could store them all in an array. I've changed my code to do that instead. I've also addressed your second question in the edit.

Comment: The code don't work tho, I don't get any product quantity in mail.

Comment: No, I mean, no code works. I'm not getting quantity by any code.

if you have a better suggestion on how to achieve this I'm listening. all I want is a form where the user selects the product he wants and how much of the product he wants and i get an email saying he wants X product 30 pieces and Y product 10 pieces.

Comment: @JamesJ. This should be working, you could try removing the `@` at the start of the POST data. It's normally just `$_POST[]`. How are you adding the code above into your program? Note I purposelly hid details in the code to show the main points. For example when you see `...` it doesn't means *"rest or the code"* not dots.

Comment: Check that the post data exist. In the HTML form you only have `quantity[1]`, `quantity[2]`, and `quantity[3]`. For debugging, just echo out each POST item to see if it's there.

Comment: Undefined index: quantity in.... That's what I get. I'm not sure if it's relevant or not, but the PHP code that I posted above is place on the bottom of the html page and the form php is posted in the middle of the html file.

Comment: @JamesJ. Yes because as I mentioned you don't have POST items such as `@$_POST['quantity[5]']`, only 1, 2, and 3. As such they will be undefined. You need to update your HTML. Also for the error, it's because arrays start at `0` not `1`. Go from `$products[0]` to `$products[9]` instead of `$products[1]` to `$products[10]`. The last item `$products[10]` isn't defined.

Comment: I have updated my html code mate. Mate, do you have an email adress or something I can send you the file and you'll see that I've done exactly as you've told me. Can't get it to work :(